Initializing WKWebView crashing app with exception
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I am using xcode 15.4, I have tested in many iOS versions it but still crashing
This is stacktrace


Is there a stacktrace? Was it working before? Is a code created one? A storyboard/xib one?

Yes before it was working but suddenly I got this issue, both programmatically and by storyboard crashes

Do you use WKWebViewConfiguration? Did you play with the languages settings in preferences?

Yes I tried with both configuration and without configuration. Yes we have localisation for two languages in the App
